# Modificar apariencia de un input

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hola les explico tengo 2 input text y quiero que en el primero
si tiene 4  o menos caracteres se pongo el formulario rojo y si tiene mas en amarillo

Lo tengo todo metido en la misma pagina y con condicionales if , pense en while pero se hace el infinito y no deja escribir , disculpar que ando algo verde

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>LOGIN</title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
                 if ($("#e1").length <= 4) {
                     $("#e1").css("background-color", "red");
            };           
                 if ($("#e1").length > 4) {
                     $("#e1").css("background-color", "yellow");
                 };
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>NOMBRE:<input type="text" id="e1" /></p><br />
    <p>EMAIL:<input type="email" /></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes gestionar alguno de los eventos de pulsación de teclas, prueba esto:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( "#id" ).keydown(function() {
             if ($("#e1").length <= 4) {
                      $("#e1").css("background-color", "red");
             };           
             if ($("#e1").length > 4) {
                      $("#e1").css("background-color", "yellow");
             };
    });
});
```

Cada vez que haya una pulsación dentro el campo se disparará la función de dentro `keydown`, testeando los `ifs`

Comment: Hola gracias por responder pero sigue igual el primer if funciona pero el segundo no hace nada siempre sigue en rojo escriba lo que escriba

Comment: Bueno ya te han dado varias respuestas validas, asi que creo que no es necesario pero supongo que el problema estaría en utilizar la propiedad length sobre el valor del campo y no directamente sobre él, tal como hacen nuestros dos compañeros, por ejemplo así: $("#e1").val().length , fallo mío que no me dí cuenta que de este modo es más correcto

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo haría de esta forma, teniendo en cuenta el rendimiento.

1. Establecería el fondo en rojo por defecto vía CSS
2. Escucharía los cambios en el input y cambiaría a amarillo sólo cuando tenga más de 4 caracteres.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#txtTest').on('input', function(e) {
    if ($(this).val().length > 4) {
      color = "yellow";
    }else{
      color = "red";
    }
    $("#txtTest").css("background-color", color);
  });
});
```

```css
#txtTest {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtTest" type="text" placeholder="Escribe al menos 5 caracteres y verás">
```

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta evidentemente funciona muy bien el codigo gracias,me surgio dudas , ESE evento e es inecesario cierto? , La variable color es pura estetica o se gana algo ? . Aun me pregunto porque no va el del compañero Xavi

Comment: Si quitas `e` te funcionará igual. La `e` es para si quieres usar algo más relativo al `evento`. Lo de la variable es _costumbre_, yo particularmente prefiero almacenar todo en variables. Supongamos que tengas varios if o un bloque `switch... case` y varias posibilidades de colores, sólo estableces el valor del color una sola vez, usando el valor que tenga la variable `color`, así no tienes que repetir esto cada vez: `$("#txtTest").css("background-color", "red");`  ... `$("#txtTest").css("background-color", "yellow");` ... `$("#txtTest").css("background-color", "green");`

Answer (score 1):

Usando el evento `keyup`*(cuando se levante una tecla)* compruebo si el `input` tiene más de 4 letras, **sin jquery**.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
 var i = document.getElementById('nombre');
 i.addEventListener('keyup',function(){
    i.style.backgroundColor = i.value.length > 4 ? 'yellow' : 'red';
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 NOMBRE:<input type="text" id="nombre">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hola yo lo puse en el evento change para que camabie dependiendo el valor.

Aquí te dejo el ejemplo y el codigo

https://jsfiddle.net/kbx6uc54/

`$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#e1').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).val().length <= 4 ){
      $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    } else {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
    }
  });
});`